# What are the common solutions of $x^2+y=31$ and $y^2+x=41$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations, roots

A friend asked me if I have a certain algorithm to solve $x^2+y = 31$ and $y^2+x=41$ simultanously. We found the solutions but we didn't find a way to solve both equations.

Any ideas?

Comment: One way is to _eliminate_ one of the variables (say, $y$) from the system, giving a quartic equation in $x$: namely, $$(31-x^2)^2 + x = 41 .$$ So solving the problem amounts to finding the roots of the quartic. [If you could guess one solution to the system, that of course helps in factoring the polynomial.]

Comment: As is already known to Lagrange, or even Euler, a system of two quadratic homogeneous equations define an elliptic curve on the plane. But your equation is not homogeneous. Therefore I might ask why did your friend ask this question? Thanks.

Comment: Then per chance you could try to solve the equations?  
$x^2+2y^2=1$  and  
$2x^2+y^2=1$  simultaneously.
It is of course interesting.

Comment: @awllower It's a very simple equation system, since you can just subtract them, and get that $x^2 = y^2$. From there I'm sure you can solve it yourself. It was never really a question about $x$ and $y$ actually, but about $x^2$ and $y^2$

Answer (score 6):

As a concrete, graphical elaboration in [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) on @Srivatsan's comment (which already answers *how* to solve it) and @Américo Tavares's solution,

```
x,y = var('x,y')
eqns = [x^2+y==31, y^2+x==41]
S = solve(eqns, [x,y], solution_dict=True)
V = [(s[x].n(digits=5), s[y].n(digits=5)) for s in S]
G = Graphics(); G.set_aspect_ratio(1)
G += implicit_plot(x^2+y==31, (x,-10,10), (y,-10,10), color="blue")
G += implicit_plot(y^2+x==41, (x,-10,10), (y,-10,10), color="green")
G += point((p for p in V), color="red", pointsize=30)
G.show()
```

[image: implicit plot of x^2+y==31, y^2+x==41 in the square (-10,10)^2]

```
V
```

[(5.0000, 6.0000), (6.0753, -5.9097), (-4.9217, 6.7766), (-6.1536, -6.8668)]

```
S
```

[{y: 6, x: 5}, {y: -5.90970873786, x: 6.07533632287}, {y: 6.77655750799, x: -4.92173189009}, {y:
-6.86684782609, x: -6.15360501567}]

```
f = x + (31-x^2)^2 - 41; f.factor() # or: latex(f.factor())
```

${\left(x - 5\right)} {\left(x^{3} + 5 \, x^{2} - 37 \, x - 184\right)}$

This cubic polynomial is irreducible over the rationals or integers, which has three real solutions:

```
plot(x^3 + 5*x^2 - 37*x - 184,(x,-10,10))
```

[image: cubic univariate polynomial plot]

For what it's worth, looking at the *exact* solutions, we can see that two are "variations" on the third, where the first term of each is multiplied by (the two nontrivial) third roots of unity, $e^{\frac{2{\pi}ik}{3}} = -\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2},\;(k=1,2)$:

```
f.roots()[0] # latex(f.roots()[0])
# gives the first root with its multiplicity
```

$\left(-\frac{1}{2} \, {\left(i \, \sqrt{3} + 1\right)} {\left(\frac{1}{18} i \, \sqrt{3}
\sqrt{27445} + \frac{3053}{54}\right)}^{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)} + \frac{68 i \, \sqrt{3} - 68}{9
\, {\left(\frac{1}{18} i \, \sqrt{3} \sqrt{27445} +
\frac{3053}{54}\right)}^{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}} - \frac{5}{3}, 1\right)$

```
f.roots()[1] # latex(f.roots()[1])
```

$\left(-\frac{1}{2} \, {\left(-i \, \sqrt{3} + 1\right)} {\left(\frac{1}{18} i \, \sqrt{3}
\sqrt{27445} + \frac{3053}{54}\right)}^{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)} + \frac{-68 i \, \sqrt{3} - 68}{9
\, {\left(\frac{1}{18} i \, \sqrt{3} \sqrt{27445} +
\frac{3053}{54}\right)}^{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}} - \frac{5}{3}, 1\right)$

```
f.roots()[2] # latex(f.roots()[2])
```

$\left({\left(\frac{1}{18} i \, \sqrt{3} \sqrt{27445} +
\frac{3053}{54}\right)}^{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)} + \frac{136}{9 \, {\left(\frac{1}{18} i \,
\sqrt{3} \sqrt{27445} + \frac{3053}{54}\right)}^{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}} - \frac{5}{3}, 1\right)
$

Comment: +1 for using open source (plus I learned some new SAGE commands)

Answer (score 5):

As Srivatsan commented we can eliminate one of the variables from the system

$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x^{2}+y=31 \\ 
y^{2}+x=41.
\end{array}
\right. $$

It is equivalent to

$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
y=31-x^{2} \\ 
x^{4}-62x^{2}+x+920=0.
\end{array}
\right. $$

A [rational solution of the quartic equation has to be a divisor of](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) $
920=2^{3}\times 5\times 23$. If we check $x=5$, we conclude that it is a
root, which we call $x_{0}$. Now we can easily factor the quartic 
$$
x^{4}-62x^{2}+x+920=\left( x-5\right) \left( x^{3}+5x^{2}-37x-184\right) $$
remaining to solve the cubic equation
$$
x^{3}+bx^{2}+cx+d=0
$$
with coefficients $b=5,c=-37,d=-184$. To get the correspondent depressed cubic equation
$$
t^{3}+pt+q=0
$$
we need to make the change of variables $x=t-b/3$ thus finding the coefficients $p=-136/3$ and $q=-3053/27$. Now we can apply the [Cardano's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method). Since
the discriminant $q^{2}+4p^{3}/27<0$ all  roots are real. One of
the roots is
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
t_{1} &=&\left( -\frac{q}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{q^{2}+\frac{4p^{3}}{27}}
\right) ^{1/3} +\left( -\frac{q}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{q^{2}+\frac{4p^{3}}{27}}\right) ^{1/3}
\\
&\approx &7.742\qquad\text{(numerical evaluation in SWP)},
\end{eqnarray*}$$
which corresponds to $x_{1}=t_{1}-5/3\approx 6.075$. The radicals are chosen
in such a way that their product is

$$\left( -\frac{q}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{q^{2}+\frac{4p^{3}}{27}}\right)
^{1/3}\left( -\frac{q}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{q^{2}+\frac{4p^{3}}{27}}\right)
^{1/3}=-\frac{p}{3}.$$

The remaining roots could also be found by factoring the cubic. Numerically we
have got $t_{2}\approx -4.487,t_{3}\approx -3.255$ and $x_{2}\approx
-6.154,x_{3}\approx -4.922$. The equation $y=31-x^{2}$ yields the values 
$y_{0}=6, y_{1}\approx -5.910$, $y_{2}\approx -6.867$, $y_{3}\approx 6.776$ (Note: rounding error of $0.001$ in comparison with bgins's evaluation).

Answer (score 3):

Rearranging gives $y^2 - x^2 = 10 + y-x,$ so that $(y-x) (y+x-1) = 10.$ You don't say you are looking for integer solutions, but if you are, then you are left with finitely many possibilities for the pair $(y-x,y+x-1),$ which can be individually solved by Gaussian elimination: for example, one possibility is $y-x = 2, y+x-1 =5,$ leading to $y = 4, x = 2.$ But this pair does not satisy the original equations. However, another possibility is $y-x = 1$ and $y+x-1 = 10,$ which leads to $y=6$ and $x=5,$ which does satisfy the original system. The other cases can be handled similarly.

Comment: I want the whole real solutions.

Comment: Then this method is not sufficient, although the fact that $x=5$ is a solution of the quartic in Srivatsan's comment should be helpful.

Comment: Notice that Srivatsan's quartic factors as $(x-5)(x^3 + 5x^2 -37x -184),$ so the remaining possibilities for $x$ that need to be checked (apart from $x=5$ which has already been dealt with) are the roots of the cubic factor.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach (Graphical approach) is to sketch the two graphs (must be drawn to scale) as found here http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Graph+x%5E2%2By%3D31+and+y%5E2%2Bx%3D41. Then determine the points of intersections of the two graphs which will give you the same set of solutions in the other approaches.

Answer (score 2):

Another way, is the combination of Srivatsan's comment and Smanoos' answer:

$\begin{cases} y=31-x^2 \\ y^2+x=41 \end{cases}$

And [for $(31-x^2)^2 + x = 41 $](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2831-x%5E2%29%5E2%20%2b%20x%20=%2041%20.&t=crmtb01):

[image]

Comment: Note, if you graph $(31-x^2)^2$ again $41-x$ and $41$, you'll see that the constant line and the $41-x$ line are dominated by the large swing in the $(31-x^2)$, so the solutions to $(31-x^2)^2=41$ give you a good "guide" of where to look for the solutions of $(31-x^2)^2=41-x$.  The solutions to the simpler equation are $\pm\sqrt{31\pm \sqrt {41}}$

Answer (score 0):

As a general algorithm for this kind of problem, you can compute a [Gröbner basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis) of the ideal generated by your polynomials, using lexicographic ordering of monomials.

The result will be a "triangular system": first a polynomial in x, then a polynomial in xy... you can solve in x, then plug the values in the second polynomial and solve in y. (cf [this paragraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis#Solving_equations) in the WP article).

[Solving Systems of Polynomial Equations](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.95.1461&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (pdf) by Bernd Sturmfels gives an introduction to the topic. If you have access to the collective book *Some Tapas of Computer Algebra* (Springer), the two first chapters will give you a very complete and clear overview of the topic.